# Same image different hover areas

Tags: jquery, hover, area

Is the following possible:

I have **one** image which I want to have different hover "detection" areas in without slicing the image into the same amount of pieces as hover areas I want. Is this a known technic or is it prefered to slice the image?

Ex: http://postimage.org/image/v6riryiov/

If the above is recommended how do I accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a container with that image as a background then define 4 `div`s inside that container, each having different id, with `width` and `height`. Something like the following:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="d1"></div>
    <div id="d2"></div>
    <div id="d3"></div>
    <div id="d4"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container { width:800px; height:800px; background:url(path/to/img.png) no-repeat }
#container > div { height:800px }
#d1, #d2 { width: 300px }
#d3 { width: 100px }
#d4 { width: 200px }
```

Comment: Ahh smart, why didn't I think of that. Thanks!

Comment: you can thank me by clicking on the hollow "V" sign besides my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Place absolute positioned Divs over the image!

You should wrap the image with a div positioned relativ!

```
<div style="position: relative;">
<img />
<div id="area1" style="position absolute; top:yourvalue; left: yourvalue;"></div>
<div id="area2" style="position absolute; top:yourvalue; left: yourvalue;"></div>
</div>
```